# Locking LUKS cryptlvm while booted?

Tags: linux, encryption, luks

I am running Arch Linux and the main / partition is LUKS encrypted. After GRUB, Plymouth asks me for the password, unlocks it and boots Arch Linux. What I'm attempting to do is quickly lock the partition with a bash script which I can link to a keybinding... however, when I use some of the following [types of] commands I obviously can't lock the partition because its OPEN. :P

```
udisksctl info -b /dev/nvme0n1p2 
udisksctl lock -b /dev/nvme0n1p2
udisksctl unlock -b /dev/nvme0n1p2
sudo cryptsetup luksClose cryptlvm
```

Am I going at this the wrong way? Should I actually just issue a 'sudo shutdown now' as the command, which will ultimately lock the partition? I'm simply wanting a killswitch that will immediately lock the partition so that any eyes or threats can't access the data.

Thanks, SO - I'm sure ya'll will make quick work of this. :/

Answer (score 2):

If you make your root filesystem inaccessible while the system is running, the filesystem drivers will be very unhappy and the system will crash. A crashed system might still hold the disk master key in RAM.

When an encrypted partition is in "unlocked" state, it means that the master key for that partition is available in kernel-controlled RAM and the device-mapper encryption/decryption layer is actively using it. When shutting the system down in any controlled fashion, the encryption/decryption layer will be stopped and the in-RAM secret (presumably) overwritten to thwart physical attacks based on chilling the RAM chips and reading their left-over contents using external devices.

For a killswitch, you would want as fast a shutdown as possible.

Try `sudo poweroff` first; if it is not fast enough for you, then perhaps `sudo poweroff -f` might be. `sudo poweroff -ff` might be even faster, but might risk some filesystem corruption, depending on which filesystem types you are using.

If you need something even faster, you might look at the [Linux "magic SysRq" commands](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html).

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> is probably the fastest reboot you can reasonably do in software. If you want to do it programmatically, `echo b | sudo tee >/proc/sysrq-trigger` or equivalent action.

If you want to use this, you might also configure your BIOS for a thorough memory test at boot, so the memory test will overwrite any secrets that might be left over in RAM by the rapid restart, just as an extra precaution.